# Google Cloud Spanner error: invalid session pool

Tags: go, google-cloud-spanner

I have the following Go code using the Spanner library:

```
package main

import (
    "log/slog"
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "context"

    "cloud.google.com/go/spanner"
)


func createClient(ctx context.Context, db string) (*spanner.Client, error) {
    sessionPoolConfig := spanner.SessionPoolConfig{
        TrackSessionHandles: true,
        InactiveTransactionRemovalOptions: spanner.InactiveTransactionRemovalOptions{
            ActionOnInactiveTransaction: spanner.WarnAndClose,
        },
    }
    dataClient, err := spanner.NewClientWithConfig(
        ctx, db, spanner.ClientConfig{SessionPoolConfig: sessionPoolConfig},
    )
        if err != nil {
        slog.Error("failed to create the spanner client", "err", err)
                return nil, err
        }
        defer dataClient.Close()

        _ = dataClient

        return dataClient, nil
}

var dbLink = "projects/PROJECT_NAME/instances/INSTANCE_NAME/databases/DATABASE_NAME"

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    snapperClient, err := createClient(ctx, dbLink)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to create a spanner client, error=%s", err.Error())
}

    row, err := spannerClient.Single().ReadRow(ctx, "DATA_TABLE", spanner.Key{THE_KEY}, []string{"THE_COLUMN"})
    if err != nil {
        slog.Error("failed to get the DATA from spanner", "error", err.Error())
        return nil, err
}
...
}
```

This is resulting in the following error log:

```
2023/11/30 22:40:03 ERROR failed to get the DATA from spanner id=4 error="spanner: code = \"InvalidArgument\", desc = \"invalid session pool\""
```

I am not convinced that this server is even reaching the Google Cloud Spanner specified database, but I didn't get a Spanner client creation error.  How can I fix this `invalid session pool` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the client inside of `createClient` before returning it. Remove `defer dataClient.Close()` and it should work as you expect.

```golang
func createClient(ctx context.Context, db string) (*spanner.Client, error) {
    sessionPoolConfig := spanner.SessionPoolConfig{
        TrackSessionHandles: true,
        InactiveTransactionRemovalOptions: spanner.InactiveTransactionRemovalOptions{
            ActionOnInactiveTransaction: spanner.WarnAndClose,
        },
    }
    dataClient, err := spanner.NewClientWithConfig(
        ctx, db, spanner.ClientConfig{SessionPoolConfig: sessionPoolConfig},
    )
    if err != nil {
        slog.Error("failed to create the spanner client", "err", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    // Remove this
    defer dataClient.Close()
    // Also this isn't doing anything
    _ = dataClient

    return dataClient, nil
}
```